# Generating a proper output layer for a Keras Model for a board game

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have created a game based on [this game here](https://sites.google.com/site/boardandpieces/list-of-games/fox--geese-checkerboard). I am attempting to use Deep Q Learning to do this, and this is my first foray into Neural networks (please be gentle!!)

I am trying to create a NN that can play this game. Here are some relevant facts about the game:

- Player 1 (the fox) has 1 piece that he can move diagonally 1 step in any direction
- Player 2(The geese) has 4 pieces that they can move only forward diagonally (either diagonal left or diagonal right) 1 step.
- The Fox wins if he reaches the other end of the board, the geese win if they trap the fox so it cannot move.

I am trying to work on the agent first for the geese as it seems to be the harder agent with more pieces and restrictions. Here is the important section of code I have so far:

> This is where I setup the game board, and set the total actions for the geese

```
def __init__(self):
    self.state_size = (LENGTH,LENGTH) ##LENGTH is 8 so (8,8)
    #...
    #other DQN variables that aren't important to question
    #...
    self.action_size = 8 ##4 geese, each can potentially make 2 moves
    self.model = self.build_model()
```

> And here is where I create my model

```
def build_model(self):
    #builds the NN for Deep-Q Model
    model = Sequential() #establishes a feed forward NN
    model.add(Dense(64,input_shape = (LENGTH,), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation = 'linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='Adam')
```

> My question: Since there are 4 geese and each can make 2 possible moves, am I correct in thinking that my action_size should be **8** (2 for each goose) or should it be maybe 2 (for diagonal left or right) or something else entirely?

The reason why I am at a loss is because on any given turn, some of the geese may have an invalid move, does that matter?

Comment: If this is your first deep learning project, directly starting with the geese might be too difficult. May I suggest that you first create an agent which "just" moves one piece around the board? You could try to train the "fox" to reach the other side of the board as quickly as possible and see whether you can get it to learn the best strategy. This should help you figure out the best setup for your agents.

Comment: I guess you could say this is my first official attempt. I have worked with MNIST and that was super easy to use. The reason why I am starting with the geese is...this is kind of my warm up for moving to chess. If I can figure out how to move the geese properly....i'd imagine making the jump to actual chess won't be impossible after this. If i get stuck I will take a step back and do the fox agent for sure!

Comment: Going from classification to Q learning is quite a big step. In your last sentence you say that "If I get stuck, I will take a step back" - and from reading your question, I think we can agree that you are in fact stuck. So I suggest you first figure out the fox without the geese, just have it learn how to reach the other side of the board as fast as possible. Then go back to geese.

Comment: Hah! well color me determined! I am working on the fox agent already slowly actually while I wait for some guidance on this. The reason why the fox is something I am working on slowly is because it is similar to the gym env Frozen Lake. I have actually worked with that as well and had some success. So that is actually what I recently "graduated" my self from. The difference there was I was relying on someone else's code heavily to understand what was going on. Here I am actually trying to code this the majority myself. I actually made the game and all the functions. I appreciate the concern!

Comment: @IonicSolutions - I have successfully implemented the Fox Agent with a DQN Network! Challenge completed!! But... now I am still stuck on this... When it comes to an agent controlling 1 single solitary piece it is easy.... but when it comes an agent controlling multiple pieces I am still at a loss.... I am going to continue to tirelessly work on this until I get my answer. I have a hypothesis though thanks to my success with the fox that I am going to try out.

Comment: I have made somewhat of a breakthrough, but I am still not 100% positive on this this is what I have done so far:
- I have mapped the moves for the geese from 0-7
- 0 being Goose 1 goes forward left
- 1 being Goose 1 goes forward right
- 2 being Goose 2 goes forward Left
- 3 being goose 2 goes forward right
...etc.

After doing this, and using the action_size of 8 and some training this seems to actually be working! I am still not 100% convinced that I have the right setup just yet.... but I am about 90% sure now as things seem to be working.